# Is grffile broken in luatex (latest update)?

Tags: graphics, luatex, includegraphics

It just happened for me since today that `grffile.sty` breaks `includegraphics` (`graphicx.sty`) in LuaTeX and makes it unable to find files. The following MWE does not work in LuaTeX but compiles normally with PdfLaTeX.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mwe}
\DeclareGraphicsExtensions{.png}
\usepackage{grffile}
\begin{document}

 \includegraphics[width=.5\linewidth]{example-image-a} 


\end{document}
```

I am using Tex Live 2019 and everything is in its last updated version. The first line of log file reads as:

> This is LuaTeX, Version 1.10.0 (TeX Live 2019)  (format=lualatex 2019.10.7)  8 OCT 2019 03:03 restricted system commands enabled.

Comment: Your example breaks with LuaLaTeX, but works fine with pdfLaTeX and XeLaTeX, so I guess it is the issue reported at https://github.com/ho-tex/oberdiek/issues/73

Comment: Thanks, yes I also guess so.

Comment: sorry about that an update to grffile and/or graphics will be available shortly but I need to decide the best place to adjust, so it may not be today. If you have any examples that you can't easily workaround ask here or on that github issue and I should be able to suggest something.

Comment: Thank you very much @DavidCarlisle. Fortunately, my image files' names do not need grffile functionality and the package was just referenced in my personal package, so I simply skipped it for Luatex. However, as a general problem with the Latex architecture, it took hours to pin down the problem in a bundle of packages and macros (for me: few thousands lines of code). I always wished Latex had a more clear, specific, and informative error reporting mechanism.

Comment: @Shahryar it is a macro expansion language and has thousands of contributed packages, that makes clear reporting of conflicts ... tricky. It is what it is.