# What are the best practices to avoid build breaking due to updating packages in LaTeX?

Tags: packages, updating, build-system

During the last month I had two occasions of build-breaking due to upgrade of some LaTeX packages. The first one was [`grffile.sty`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/511368/is-grffile-broken-in-luatex-latest-update?noredirect=1#comment1293195_511368) and then today `xpatchcmd` (no idea which library defined it before, but I fixed it by adding/replacing `regexpatch` library).

My question is how one can avoid those build-breaking cases and have a stable bundle (LaTeX code + required libraries) that can persist for a long time. The general recommendations, such as having less dependencies, do not help to make sure this does not happen in future.

I can reformulate my question as:

1. Is there a way to have a snapshot of all required packages that are working at the moment, bundle them together? Containers, such as `docker` might be a solution (not sure).
2. Is there a way to record the last working versions of packages (directly or indirectly used) and return back to the last working set by running a script (similar mechanism as `npm` in NodeJS)?
3. Is there a way to compare the output PDF files (before and after an upgrade of packages) to notice visual changes (just comparing files, e.g. using hash functions, does not help since there might be changes due to improvements)

**Edit:**

***Somehow like an MVE:***
Consider I want to minimally store everything needed to recreate a PDF document from TeX source. 10 years later, I want to update the TeX document and expect to be able to build a PDF (from the backup) which only reflects my update on the content. To backup the whole distribution is a way, but it is of course not minimal.

Comment: question has to be asked, why did you update? if working on a document then typically there is no pressing need to update the latex system, if you do update (and pick up a major update like a new 2019-10-01 latex release) then it's advisable to not lock down your system and accept following updates as there can be issues.

Comment: Some reasons for update:

1- "Tex Live Utility" every now and then nags about available updates (and sometimes 'critical update'), and sometimes I react by pushing the update button (but can take your advice for major updates, how?). 

2-The last document I was working took me around 3 years to complete and I had the feeling that keeping updated with packages is a good practice in general. 

3- Also, I created a big package (4K lines of code, referring >160 packages) for myself that provides every features I need. It increases the potential for problem, but no other way.

Comment: well I'm not sure what general advice there can be, the contributed grffile package patched latex internals to add some features, latex 2019-10-01 added similar features anyway so grffile stopped working. it was updated the next day, to do nothing, but an error in the texlive packaging meant that for a few hours there was no grffile at all as the directory got distributed empty, I don't see what general procedure could avoid that other than don't update, or keep updating as someone will fix it in the next hour or so..

Comment: texlive has a backup/restore system, see https://www.tug.org/texlive/doc/tlmgr.html#restore. miktex hasn't, so in doubt make a backup of the whole install folder. It is imho sensible to regularly update - problems can then be handled one by one, but it doesn't harm to wait a few days and check if somewhere bugs are mentioned before clicking on the update button.

Comment: If you have Norton Security Suite, you can set it up to back up the entire tex library in a separate file.  You would have to add sty and tex to the extension list.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Thanks! This is a solution. Though, if it could backup nesting and intelligently only the dependencies of a document or a local package that would be much better.

Comment: check https://ctan.org/topic/bundle.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer bundledoc seems to be the answer. Thanks a lot!